# raspberry pi openelec: how to connect via wifi with an ssid with spaces and special characters

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, kodi, ssid

```
device: Raspberry Pi Mod. B Rev 2.0 512 MB RAM
wifi stick: EDIMAX EW-7811UN Wireless USB Adapter, 150 Mbit/s
OS: openelec (XBMC)
ssid: FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7270
```

How can I connect to wireless lan with a ssid with spaces and special character (*ex. !*).
I have tried Raspbmc and it worked, but it is too slow.

I have seen in an article that special characters could be escaped like this `FRITZ\!Box\ Fon\ WLAN\ 7270`

Comment: Did you solve this ever?